# GAE Datastore generate String key with JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

Since it isn't possible to use only Long Ids I am trying to use the generated String keys. I have three Classes `User`, `Topic`, `Comments` with `User` - 1:n - `Topic` - 1:n -`Comments`.

**Class Comment:**

```
@Entity
public class Comment implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String key;
    @ManyToOne
    private User author;
    @ManyToOne
    private Topic topic;
```

**Class User:**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String key;

    @Unique
    private String username;
```

**Class Topic:**

```
@Entity
public class Topic implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String key;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User author;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments;
```

Now when I am trying to save a new User, the following exception occurs

```
Invalid primary key for User.  Cannot have a null primary key field if the field is unencoded and of type String.  Please provide a value or, if you want the datastore to generate an id on your behalf, change the type of the field to Long.
```

Is it possible to let the String ID get generated without manually using the KeyFactory? If yes whats wrong with my code?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIRC IDENTITY strategy is to generate numeric (or Key) ids. 
If you were using JDO you could use UUID-style ids auto-generated.
See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Keys

Answer (score 0):

I use `TableGenerator`. It is useful whatever you `want` id style. Let's say even if you would like to get `Group` id like `GRP0000001` and `GRP0000500` etc..
You have to use property injection, not field injection in your entity. It is based on your setter ID method. If generated id is 201 by `EntityManager` generate, entity manager will call `setId()` in setter injection. If so, the id will be `GRP0000201`.

My Example:

```
@Entity
@TableGenerator(name = "GROUP_GEN", table = "ID_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", 
                valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "GROUP_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Group implements Serializable {
    @Transient
    private String id;
    private String name;
    //name getter and setter
    public void setId(String id) {
        if(id != null) {
            this.id = Utils.formatId(id, "GRP", 10);    
        }
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "GROUP_GEN")
    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Utils.java

```
public class Utils {
    /**
     * E.g.
     * Input: id=523, prefix="AAA", maxLength=15
     * Output: AAA000000000523
     */
    public static String formatId(String id, String prefix, int maxLength) {
        if (!id.startsWith(prefix)) {
            int length = id.length() + prefix.length();
            for (; (maxLength - length) > 0; length++) {
                id = '0' + id;
            }
            id = prefix + id;
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```